# When more than one URL present in Core Data, the url is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, url, core-data, video

I have an app with a camera that takes a video, which then has a photo thumbnail in a `UITableView`. For every cell, a URL is assigned that is the corresponding video to the thumbnail. To do this, I store both the video and the thumbnail in Core Data. The first time I create a video, it works fine but the second time, the url is being retrieved.

Here is the code to save the video:

```
- (void) saveVideo {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    FeedEntity *feed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FeedEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *stringForSave = [self.videoURL absoluteString];

    NSData * stringData = [stringForSave dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [feed setValue: stringData forKey:@"urlString"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } else {

    }        
}
```

Here is the code where I retrieve it:

```
FeedEntity *feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSData *data = feed.imageData;

NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
self.stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.stringForURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: You're only saving the video's URL to the persistent store, not the video itself. Is that what you want?

Comment: I thought it was best to not save the video to core data because it is too big. I was just saving the URL and then saving the video elsewhere. Is it ok to save to core data as long as external storage is checked? @bilobatum

Comment: My comment was poorly worded. It sounds like you're persisting the video itself on your own using an URL and storing the URL in Core Data. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking "Allows External Storage" for an attribute in the data model, then you should save the video *itself*, not an URL, to the context as a bag of bits (i.e., `NSData`). When you check "Allows External Storage", you are telling Core Data that it can decide whether or not to save the large file inside or outside the persistent store. You don't need to persistent the large file yourself.

Comment: Hi, One question, I was just setting it up this way and I was wondering what the best way to display the video after saving. Should I try to get a URL out of the data or what?

Comment: Or is there a way to just use the data?